# How to identify a post is NEW or we are editing an existing one?

Tags: wordpress

How do we identify that we are on a NEW Post page or editing an existing one from within the code.

I checked with $post->ID it returns POST ID in case of new Post also.

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to use add_action such as:

```
function editing_flag(){
     //set a flag to the post being edited
}
add_action('edit_post','editing_flag');
```

then in a single.php, you check if the flag is set like:

```
if(flag){
    echo 'the post is being edited';
}
```

but remeber to unflag it when you are done editing. this is just an idea

Comment: I think we are little far away from the solution. Let me describe you about my problem in little details. I am writing a Plugin for Feeds Aggregator and Feed Item Poster to Tweeter. So In the Form where user can enter new feed url, I want to check if Post (FEED) is new or EDITED one. Didn't find something to use.